# 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'add_served'

Tags: python

I want to make it so I can update the number of meals served for the day. For some reason I get this error:

> 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'add_served'

and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
class Restaurant:

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):

        self.describe_restaurant = restaurant_name + ' ' + cuisine_type

    def served(self, number_served):

        self.number_served = 0
        return number_served

    def add(self, add_number):

        self.add += add_number



rest = Restaurant("LOL", "HEHE")
print(rest.served(5))
print(rest.add(12))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `self.number_served` need to be declared at `def __init__`.

```py
class Restaurant:

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):

        self.describe_restaurant = restaurant_name + ' ' + cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0

    def served(self, number_served):

        self.number_served = 0 #what are you doing?
        return number_served

    def add(self, add_number):

        self.add += add_number
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add `add_number` to `self.add` which you didn't declared.
first you need to initialized `self.add`

```py
class Restuarant:
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        ...
        self.add = 0 # set 0 for default value
```

then you need to rename `add` function name because when you are trying to add `add_number` to `self.add` it thinks you are trying to call the function

```py
def _add(self, add_number):

        self.add += add_number
        # return whatever you want
        return self.add
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is just telling you that you are trying to call an attribute you didnt define.
To use "self", your attribute has to defined under the init function.
For your add function, I believe what you want to do is to add a new number to the number of people served. You can just do that by defining the attribute "number_served"(Which will make it available for all the function in that class),calling  the attribute and adding the number(no need of creating  another attribute "add").
I believe this is what you want to do:

```
class Restaurant:
    
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):

        self.number_served = 0
        self.describe_restaurant = restaurant_name + ' ' + cuisine_type

    def served(self, number_served):

        self.number_served = number_served
        return number_served

    def add(self, add_number):

        self.number_served += add_number
        return self.number_served


rest = Restaurant("LOL", "HEHE")
print(rest.describe_restaurant)
print(rest.served(5))
print(rest.add(12))
```